# XSLT - removing nil=true & empty elements

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I use the below xslt to remove namespaces. Is there a way to modify this in order to remove elements with nil="true" and empty tags (eg: `<data/>`)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work , however please suggest if there is a more efficient way to do this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />


    <!-- TEMPLATE #1 -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- TEMPLATE #2 -->
    <xsl:template match="*[@xsi:nil = 'true']" />

    <xsl:template
        match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) 
                 and 
                 normalize-space()='']" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't see much room for improvement, but one thing to note: this will remove elements that contain comments, attributes, and processing instructions if they contain an `xsi:nil="true"` attribute. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks @JLRishe for highlighting the potential issue. As of now the xml data that I am using doesn't have attributes.

Comment: There's a problem in this code in that the template rules are ambiguous. It's possible for an element to match both rules 2 and 3 (and they have the same priority); equally, attributes will match both rules 1 and 5. Elements match both rules 1 and 4, but that's less of a problem because rule 4 has higher priority. If there are two rules that match a node with the same priority, then exactly what happens depends on which version of XSLT you're using, and with XSLT 1.0 it depends on which processor you are using. So it's safest not to allow it to happen, by specifying priorities.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you very much!!